# Java obfuscated file with proguard runs on default folder but does not run on any folder

Tags: java, proguard

I'm stuck trying to obfuscate a java program with proguard 7.3.2 on windows 10 and jdk 9.

Some facts:

1. original jar runs well on the default folder (/dist)
2. original jar DOES NOT run on any other folder. The program does not start ("java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook")
3. if i create an exe file of the original jar file with Launch4j, it runs on the default folder
4. the exe file of the original jar runs everywhere.
5. if i obfuscate the jar file, it runs fine on the default folder (/dist) same as the original jar, which is great.
6. the obfuscated jar does not run on another folder. The program does not start (same error as above)
7. if i create an exe file of the obfuscated jar file with Launch4j, it runs well on the default folder
8. the exe file of the obfuscated jar does not run on any other folder. The program does not start (same error as before).
9. when i compile the java program, another jar file with all the libraries is created.
10. the full jar file runs on it's default folder (/Executable)
11. the full jar file runs on any folder, no error shows
12. if I obfuscate this full jar file and it runs on the default folder (/Executable), a different error shows when tries the connection with the database. The program actually runs. Therefore, nothing to do with the previous error.
13. if I run this obfuscated jar of the full jar on a different folder, the program runs and I get the error when tries the database connection.

I'm aware poi dependencies are crucial therefore I've checked twice all of them are installed (attached).

I've made several changes on the proguard configuration with no success (with/without keep directories ...attached the last configuration).

I need that either the obfuscated jar or the exe file created with it, runs on any folder.

Any idea will be welcome.

Thanks a lot,

POI dependencies:

[poi dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qHea.png)

Proguard configuration:

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-keepdirectories **
-forceprocessing
-dontoptimize
-keeppackagenames **
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariableTable,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod,SourceDir,EnclosigMethod
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-dontnote
-dontwarn



# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main' methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Also keep - Database drivers. Keep all implementations of java.sql.Driver.
-keep class * extends java.sql.Driver

# Also keep - Swing UI L&F. Keep all extensions of javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI,
# along with the special 'createUI' method.
-keep class * extends javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI {
    public static javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI createUI(javax.swing.JComponent);
}

# Keep - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,includedescriptorclasses,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Remove - System method calls. Remove all invocations of System
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.System {
    ...
}

# Remove - Math method calls. Remove all invocations of Math
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.Math {
    ...
}

# Remove - Number method calls. Remove all invocations of Number
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.* extends java.lang.Number {
    ...
}

# Remove - String method calls. Remove all invocations of String
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.String {
    ...
}

# Remove - StringBuffer method calls. Remove all invocations of StringBuffer
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.StringBuffer {
    ...
}

# Remove - StringBuilder method calls. Remove all invocations of StringBuilder
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.StringBuilder {
    ...
}



I need an obfuscated file that runs everywhere, not only on the default folder (/dist).
```